# Pegar todos os dados com o mesmo id sem saber o id

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com informações que possuem o mesmo ID, como se fossem um conjunto, gostaria de pegar todas as informações com esse ID, porém não o tenho, e estou usando um LIKE para buscar termos desse conjunto, algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM josyo_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName LIKE :term
```

Porém isto só me retorna o id da informação e somente uma informação, gostaria de que no resultado da busca seja retornado todas as informações com o ID da busca, não entendo muito de SQL, mas acredito que seja algum tipo de relação

Exemplo:

```
ID / FieldName / FieldValue
20 / Carro / Ferrari
20 / Nome / Virgulino
20 / Sexo / Masculino
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode pegar essa informação fazendo um `join` da tabela com ela mesma:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    josyo_rsform_submission_values t1 
    INNER JOIN josyo_rsform_submission_values t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHERE
    t1.FieldName LIKE :term
```

### Construção da consulta

Ok, vamos explicar aos poucos.

Queremos pegar todas as tuplas que tenham um `id`. Para isso, precisamos obter o `id` de algum jeito, porém a informação básica que temos é `FieldName`.

Podemos pegar o `id` da linha dessa tabela que contenha essa informação como você fez acima:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    josyo_rsform_submission_values
WHERE
    FieldName LIKE :term
```

Pronto, agora precisamos pegar todas as linhas de uma tabela que casem com essa informação. Se eu tratar como tabelas diferentes, `t1` e `t2`, preciso de todas as informações de `t2` que se juntam a `t1` através do `id`. Essa forma de pensamento indica que podemos usar um `join`; só juntar as informações de uma `t1` e `t2` quaisquer seria assim:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t1
    INNER JOIN t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Se quisermos apenas as informações de `t2`:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    t1
    INNER JOIN t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Usando o nome correto para as tabelas:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    josyo_rsform_submission_values t1
    INNER JOIN josyo_rsform_submission_values t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Filtrando pela informação desejada em `t1`:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    josyo_rsform_submission_values t1
    INNER JOIN josyo_rsform_submission_values t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHERE
    t1.FieldName LIKE :term
```

> **UPDATE**: não tinha ficado muito claro na primeira versão da resposta como funciona a junção de uma tabela nela mesma

### Explicando a auto junção

Tomemos um conjunto de dados. Vamos dizer que ele é o conjunto `X`. Para questão de facilidade de entendimento, meu conjunto de dados pertence a [image: N^2]. Também vou dizer que o primeiro campo desses dados se chama `id`, e o segundo campo se chama `value`. O meu conjunto de dados `X` é:

```
(1, 12)
(1, 100)
(2, 15)
(2, 37)
(2, 0)
```

Eu posso pegar todos os elementos em `X` que tenham `id = 1`. A notação em [álgebra relacional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) é algo parecido com:

[image: X selecionado por id = 1]

Assim, o resultado dessa expressão algébrica é:

```
(1, 12)
(1, 100)
```

Então, o que seria o resultado da seguinte expressão?

[image: X selecionado por id = 1, renomeando id para id1; X renomeando id para id2; junção natural de id1 e id2]

Por partes:

1. na parte esquerda, temos a seleção de antes
2. dada essa seleção, faço um renomeio de `id` para `id1`; isso significa que o resultado dessa operação agora terá a coluna `id1` e a coluna `value`
3. operação de junção natural do conjunto a esquerda (acabamos de definir ele no passo anterior) com o conjunto a direita, ainda a ser definido; a junção é feita usando `id1 = id2`
4. do conjunto de dados `X` faço o renomeio de `id` para `id2`; note que em nenhuma das operações até agora o valor do cnjunto de dados `X` foi alterado

Mostrando os resultados de cada operação:

1. na parte esquerda, temos a seleção de antes

   ```
   [id, value]
   (1, 12)
   (1, 100)
   ```
2. dada essa seleção, faço um renomeio de `id` para `id1`; isso significa que o resultado dessa operação agora terá a coluna `id1` e a coluna `value`

   ```
   [id1, value]
   (1, 12)
   (1, 100)
   ```
3. do conjunto de dados `X` faço o renomeio de `id` para `id2`; note que em nenhuma das operações até agora o valor do cnjunto de dados `X` foi alterado

   ```
   [id2, value]
   (1, 12)
   (1, 100)
   (2, 15)
   (2, 37)
   (2, 0)
   ```

> Sobre o passo 3... Uma junção é composta por um produto cartesiano seguido de uma seleção, portanto vou dividir em dois passos 3 (3.a e 3.b)

3. a. com o conjunto a direita

   ```
   [id1, value, id2, value]
   (1,   12,    1, 12)
   (1,   12,    1, 100)
   (1,   12,    2, 15)
   (1,   12,    2, 37)
   (1,   12,    2, 0)

   (1,   100,   1, 12)
   (1,   100,   1, 100)
   (1,   100,   2, 15)
   (1,   100,   2, 37)
   (1,   100,   2, 0)
   ```
4. b. a junção é feita usando `id1 = id2`

   ```
   [id1, value, id2, value]
   (1,   12,    1, 12)
   (1,   12,    1, 100)
   (1,   100,   1, 12)
   (1,   100,   1, 100)
   ```

Agora imagina que você não quer mais fazer o filtro por `id = 1`, mas por `value = 100`. Assim, teríamos a seguinte expressão:

[image: X selecionado por value = 100, renomeando id para id1; X renomeando id para id2; junção natural de id1 e id2]

O resultado dessa operação é:

```
[id1, value, id2, value]
(1,   100,   1, 12)
(1,   100,   1, 100)
```

E é mais ou menos isso que você queria no começo. Tem algumas mudanças quando se muda de álgebra relacional para SQL (por exemplo, a operação `rô` de renomeio é feito no conjunto de dados, não na coluna), mas a ideia geral é essa.

Comment: Todos os dados são da mesma tabela, então seria só repetir t1 no lugar de t2, certo?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, não entendi esse seu comentário. Posso tentar reformular minha resposta numa abordagem mais matemática para deixar tudo mais claro, mas continuo sem entender essa repetição de `t1` no lugar de `t2`

Comment: você usou t1 e t2 como exemplos de duas tabelas distintas, mas os dados estão somente em t1, no caso a relação seria de t1 para t1

Comment: Entendi sua dúvida. Isso pode parece um pouco confuso a primeira vista, self-join, mas é plausível. Eu peguei duas cópias do mesmo conjunto de dados (digamos assim); o conjunto de dados `x` pode ser chamado de `t1`, e posso pegar uma cópia de `x` e chamar de `t2`, fazendo assim um join de `x` em `x`. Vou tentar atualizar minha resposta de modo mais aprofundado

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, atualizei minha resposta e pus um pouco de álgebra relacional. A grosso modo, SQL tenta implementar essa álgebra, então os pensamentos da álgebra podem ser aplicados em SQL

Comment: Desculpa, mas ainda não consegui implementar, ficou um pouco confuso