# Consulta SQL com duplicidade de itens

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho essa situação e não sei o porque acontece. Quando eu passo esse comando SQL os itens mostrados vem duplicados. O que devo fazer para aparecer um item de cada sem por o `DISTICT`

```
SELECT                                          
  T1.*                                        
FROM                                            
  CONSULTAS T1,                               
  PARAMETROS T2                               
WHERE                                           
 (T1.DATA_CADASTRO <= T2.DATA_SISTEMA-14)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia ter sido mais especifíco em sua pergunta! Qual a função a entidade (tabela) consultas e parametros especifique esses relacionamentos quais as chaves primárias. Se houver uma chave de relacionamento o correto era usar JOIN  para essa consulta!

Comment: qual o problema de usar o distinct? os itens serão repetidos quantas vezes aparecerem dentro da tabela parâmetros, coloque a estrutura das tabelas e qual o proposito da query para que possamos ajudar

Comment: Teria que ser mais específico na pergunta. Precisaria mostrar o que há em suas tabelas, se possível.

Comment: Então se não houver outra maneira usarei o distinct...

Comment: A única relação entre as duas tabelas é a data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo meu entendimento, você quer perguntar o seguinte:

> Quais são as consultas que tiveram parâmetros em até 14 dias após seu cadastro?

Se for essa a pergunta, então o relacionamento está incompleto. Não consigo dizer qual consultas teve parâmetros.

Agora, se sua pergunta for:

> Quais consultas que estão a pelo menos 14 dias de algum parâmetro?

Posso responder com uma subconsulta:

```
SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    CONSULTAS C
WHERE
    EXISTS (
         SELECT
             1
         FROM
             PARAMETROS P
         WHERE
             C.DATA_CADASTRO <= P.DATA_SISTEMA - 14
    )
```

Transcrição dessa subconsulta para português:

> Se existe pelo menos um parâmetro criado pelo menos 14 dias depois de uma consulta, essa consulta deve ser exibida

---

Note que não estou fazendo um produto cartesiano no `FROM`. Com o produto cartesiano como você fez, para cada `PARAMETROS` que atendesse ao `WHERE`, seria retornada uma nova linha. Eu discorro mais sobre produto cartesiano em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214566/64969). No seu caso, a projeção é somente de `CONSULTAS`, portanto aparenta ser a mesma linha repetida.

Como eu coloquei a tabela `PARAMETROS` como uma condição de filtragem, não como produto cartesiano, não há multiplicação de registros.

Comment: Beleza vou dar uma lida e fazer os teste com você sugeriu...

Comment: assim resolveu minha duvida ficou bem legal. Então toda vez que uma tabela não fizer associação a outra na consulta e eu precisara usar uns dos campos para comparação terei que fazer mais ou menos desse modo?

Comment: Não vou responder de caso geral. Cada caso é um caso. Inclusive estou vendo aqui como colocar questões de performance. Falar de um modo mais amigável "faça o teste para saber a performance"

Comment: Entendo dependendo do caso... posso fazer...

Answer (score 2):

Suponha que a tabela T1 seja:

```
id     nome    data_cadastro
```

```
1      joão    09/07/2017
2      maria   10/07/2017
```

e a tabela T2 seja:

```
id     t1_id    data_sistema
```

```
1      1        09/07/2017
2      1        10/07/2017
```

Quando você faz:

```
SELECT T1.*  FROM  CONSULTAS T1, PARAMETROS T2                               
WHERE (T1.DATA_CADASTRO <= T2.DATA_SISTEMA-14)
```

a quantidade de registros retornados é o produto entre as linhas das duas tabelas. Nessa consulta especifica seriam quatro (o correto seria no maximo 2 que é a quantidade máxima de registros em cada tabela).Nessa consulta é feita a combinação das linha das duas tabela envolvidas.

Para evitar a situação descrita acima, deve-se relacionar as duas tabelas de alguma maneira. No exemplo há uma relação indicada pela chave estrangeira t1_id na tabela T2. Colocando essa relação na consulta fica:

```
SELECT T1.*  FROM  CONSULTAS T1, PARAMETROS T2                               
WHERE T1.id = T2.t1_id and (T1.DATA_CADASTRO <= T2.DATA_SISTEMA-14)
```

Comment: Na verdade elas não tem relação alguma eu só pego a data do sistema que está na tabela de PARAMETROS para fazer a comparação

Comment: casos a data for das consultas forem menor eu vou fazer outro sql para apagar as consultas antigas...