# Consulta retornando valores duplicados

Tags: sql, firebird

gente eu postei aqui no tópico [Consulta SQL com duplicidade de itens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219331/consulta-sql-com-duplicidade-de-itens)
só que estou com outra duvida...
tenho a sql:

```
SELECT 
  TABNOV.CODIGO_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.NUMERO_PROCESSO,
  TABNOV.INSTANCIA,
  TABNOV.DESCRICAO_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.ACESSO_PUBLICO,
  TABNOV.DATA,
  TABNOV.DATA_INCLUSAO,
  TABNOV.HORA,
  TABNOV.EMAIL_ENVIADO,
  TABNOV.CODIGO_PUBLICACAO,
  TABNOV.CODIGO_CONSULTA,
  TABNOV.CODIGO_AUDIENCIA,
  TABNOV.CODIGO_AGENDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.USUARIO_CADASTRO,
  TABNOV.USUARIO_ALTERACAO,
  TABNOV.DATA_ALTERACAO,
  TABNOV.HORA_ALTERACAO,
  TABNOV.OBSERVACAO,
  TABNOV.NOME_IMAGEM_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX,
  TABNOV.ATO_FATURAVEL
FROM                                                                 
  ( SELECT
      T1.*
    FROM
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO)
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO LIKE "ARQUIVADO")
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT                                                             
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO2)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO2 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT                                                             
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO3)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO3 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")                         
    UNION ALL                                                       
    SELECT                                                        
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO4)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO4 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")                         
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO5)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO5 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")                         
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT                                                            
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO6)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO6 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")                         
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT                                                             
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO7)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO7 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")                         
    UNION ALL                                                          
    SELECT                                                             
      T1.*                                                              
    FROM                                                               
      ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T1                                         
      LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
    WHERE (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO8)               
    AND   (T2.FASE_PROCESSO8 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")) TABNOV
```

e ela na verdade segue mais seis `Unions` só que alguns dos item aparece duplicado e no momento de passar os itens da query para a Tabela da erro de duplicidade de PK não sei o que fazer pois o registro na tabla principal não está duplicado?

Estrutura da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS (
  CODIGO_ANDAMENTO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NUMERO_PROCESSO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  INSTANCIA INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DESCRICAO_ANDAMENTO VARCHAR(200),
  ACESSO_PUBLICO VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  DATA DATE NOT NULL,
  DATA_INCLUSAO DATE,
  HORA VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL_ENVIADO VARCHAR(1),
  CODIGO_PUBLICACAO INTEGER,
  CODIGO_CONSULTA INTEGER,
  CODIGO_AUDIENCIA INTEGER,
  CODIGO_AGENDAMENTO INTEGER,
  USUARIO_CADASTRO VARCHAR(15),
  USUARIO_ALTERACAO VARCHAR(15),
  DATA_ALTERACAO DATE,
  HORA_ALTERACAO VARCHAR(5),
  OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(8100),
  NOME_IMAGEM_ANDAMENTO VARCHAR(50),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ATO_FATURAVEL VARCHAR(1));
ALTER TABLE ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO_ANDAMENTO);

ALTER TABLE ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AND_NUMERO_PROCESSO FOREIGN KEY (NUMERO_PROCESSO) REFERENCES PROCESSOS(NUMERO_PROCESSO);

CREATE TABLE PROCESSOS (
  NUMERO_PROCESSO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  FASE_PROCESSO VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  NUMERO_PROCESSO2 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO2 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO3 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO3 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO4 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO4 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_E_VARA4 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO5 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO5 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO6 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO6 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO7 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO7 VARCHAR(25),
  NUMERO_PROCESSO8 VARCHAR(30),
  FASE_PROCESSO8 VARCHAR(25),
  OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(2000));
```

Comment: coloque o código completo com as unions e a estrutura das tabelas, se possível monte um sqlfiddle

Comment: O Código está completo agora e a estrutura da tabela não da no cometario

Comment: Não sei se isso e erro do FireDac ou coisa do Firebird teste a SQL no SGBD e quando eu passo um por um não duplica mais se eu pedir para ir para o ultimo registro de vez ele duplica.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta colocando a estrutura. Já tentou fazer sem esses `Union All` ?

Comment: não sou tão experiente em SQL com seria sem o `union All`?

Comment: Só com `union` , `union all` traz todos os registros, mesmo que duplicados, só o Union não

Comment: a blz vou tentar fazer e ver como vai ficar

Comment: Essa querie vai ter gerar vários problemas de performance, eu acredito que tenha como esreve-la de forma mais enxuta, você poderia alterar sua pergunta dizendo quais registros gostaria de buscar? Além disso o uso do coringa * que serve para buscar todos os atributos  da tabela não é aconselhavel porque deixa a querie exageradamente mais lenta uma vez que obriga o SGBD a selecionar todos os atributos de cada tabela consultada variaz vezes. Dependento do tipo dos atributos se for um varchar por exemplo pode piorar ainda mais os tempos de execução.

Comment: mais na query já diz quais os registros preciso buscar... pois eu vou passar todos os registros de processos com a fase Arquivado para tabela de Histórico

Comment: Diz sim, mas não explica o que são esses campos T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO7 o que efetivamente está buscando?

Comment: Em condições como essa não se executa uma querie dessas em tempo de execução, ao contrário disso cria-se uma view ou então um evento que executa um stored e guarda em uma tabela a parte o resultado da execução. Estou apenas orientando para que no futuro quando a tabela ganhar registros não venha a te dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: esse campos são processo que que estão ligados ao processo Principal eles podem ou não ter andamentos e todos os andamentos são mostrado a partir do principal.

Comment: como eu disse acima eu não sou experiente em SQL...

Comment: Não use UNION vc tem a chave estrangeira entre as tabelas você está desejando resgatar o processo e todos os seus andamentos correto ? vc pode montar tudo isso com left joins sem o union.

Comment: eu quero resgatar todos os andamentos sendo do principal e dos 7 se houver.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62174/discussion-between-rafael-salomao-and-eduardo-mendonca-da-silva).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que possa fazer isso:

```
SELECT 
  TABNOV.CODIGO_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.NUMERO_PROCESSO,
  TABNOV.DESCRICAO_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.DATA,
  TABNOV.DATA_INCLUSAO,
  TABNOV.HORA,
  TABNOV.EMAIL_ENVIADO,
  TABNOV.CODIGO_PUBLICACAO,
  TABNOV.HORA_ALTERACAO,
  TABNOV.NOME_IMAGEM_ANDAMENTO,
  TABNOV.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX,
  TABNOV.ATO_FATURAVEL
FROM PROCESSOS T1 
LEFT JOIN ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T2 
ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO
AND (T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX )
AND   (T1.FASE_PROCESSO LIKE "ARQUIVADO")

LEFT JOIN ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T3                                        
T2 ON T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO 
AND T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO2 = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX)               
AND  (T1.FASE_PROCESSO2 LIKE "ARQUIVADO")
```

Você poderia fazer vários left join como esse se repetindo e filtrando os resultados pelos campos que deseja. A QUERY acima pega todos os registros da tabela processos e seus relacionamentos se existirem com a tabela andamentos processuais.

Eu não tenho certeza que daria certo. Precisaria das tabelas com os dados para fazer testes de performance e se funciona adequadamente ao que deseja e não tenho entendimento total sobre o que quer fazer. Mas é uma tentativa de eliminar todos esses UNIONS consomem um exagero de CPU de sua maquina e geram tabelas temporárias que consomem muita memoria. Se existir quantidade de usuários executando essa mesma querie  ao mesmo tempo poderia consumir todo o recurso de seu servidor.

Comment: só um dos usuários que vai fazer essa consulta e sempre no final do expediente.

Comment: eu vou fazer os testes aqui e completar a query com os outros campos

Comment: A Query está demorando muito para exibir os resultados, Passando dos 15 minutos...

Comment: Fora que a query mostra todos os registros