# Identificando irmãos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Eu montei este link como exemplo de onde quero chegar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72f4b5/4

Tenho a tabela de alunos.
[image: tab_alunos]
Tenho a tabela com os ids de irmãos
[image: tab_irmaos]

Meu problema é, preciso fazer um select de tal maneira que eu consiga fazer aparecer um nome somente de cada vez assim e produzindo uma ID para linkar os irmãos: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

 Com essa query

```
SELECT  * FROM ALUNOS A 
INNER JOIN ALUNOS_IRMAOS AI
ON A.COD_ALUNO = AI.COD_ALUNO
WHERE A.COD_ALUNO = AI.COD_ALUNO OR A.COD_ALUNO = AI.COD_ALUNO
GROUP BY A.COD_ALUNO, A.NM_ALUNO, A.NM_PAI, A.NM_MAE
```

consegui chegar no seguinte resultado: 
[image: resultado 2]

Preciso de uma query que me ajude a chegar no resultado da imagem 3.

Comment: E se o Gabriel fosse irmão do Vitor, o Vitor fosse irmão do Geovanne, mas o Geovanne e o Gabriel não fossem irmãos? O Vitor pertenceria a dois códigos únicos de irmão (um que seria compartilhado com o Gabriel e outro com o Geovanne)?

Comment: Sim

Como no caso da tabela de irmãos está:

Gabriel para Vitor ;
Gabriel para Geovanne;;

Vitor para Gabriel ;
Vitor para Geovanne;;

Geovanne para Gabriel ; e Geovanne para vitor ;;

A relação que existe no banco de dados é esta.

Eu ainda não conheço as regras de negócio dos programas que alimentam este banco, então não tenho certeza se é válido para meio irmãos. mas por enquanto eu quero desse jeito, contado com meio-irmãos.

Comment: Ignore como tua tabela está atualmente, eu criei uma situação hipotética para entender melhor como montar a consulta. A não ser que você me diga que nunca vai existir, mas ainda assim o ideal seria que a consulta previsse essa situação.

Comment: agora você me pegou, não posso prever tudo dessa plataforma, mas por enquanto eu queria pegar do jeito que está, todos os irmãos conectados igual está na tabela que eu criei no link.

Comment: Ok, só mais uma coisa. Você marcou a tag `sql-server` mas fez um Fiddle usando MySQL. Qual dos dois você de fato precisa?

Comment: Aqui é SQL Server, mas não tem problema ser em MYSQL.

Comment: Você tem uma tabela de "responsáveis" ou "pai" e mãe" são colunas da tabela de alunos , no segundo caso eu reveria o modelo , mas de qualquer forma um subselect resolve : select * from aluno a where exists (select null from aluno a2 where a2.nm_pai = a1.nm_pai or a2.nm_mae = a1.nm_mae)

Comment: Não tenho tabela de responsáveis, são apenas colunas. E pode acontecer do aluno não ter os pais. ou não ter um dos pais, etc.

Comment: Tem algum problema o `COD_UNICO_DOS_IRMAIS` não ser consecutivo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha ideia é semelhante à [ideia do @Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230428/64969), porém estou tentando fazer sem juntar pelo nome dos pais. No caso, defino uma `IRMANDADE` (nome emprestado da [proposta do @AlexandreCavaloti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230875/64969)) e então junto com o aluno, retornando um *código de irmandade* arbitrário.

> Não tentei tratar para o caso generalizado, onde a irmandade é definida por um grafo generalizado, e cliques são sempre irmãos que compartilham ambos os pais. A solução proposta aqui oferece a resposta correta para cliques de irmãos, outros formatos de grafos podem trazer respostas esquisitas.

### Determinando o código do clique

Como todos os irmãos estão ligados, usar como código do clique um dos códigos de um dos irmãos garante que os códigos entre um agrupamento de irmão nunca irá conflitar com o código de outro agrupamento de irmãos. Para sempre pegar o mesmo código no clique, define que vai ser o menor código de aluno pertencente ao clique.

Assim, temos as seguintes irmandades:

```
COD_ALUNO | COD_IRMANDADE
1         | 1
2         | 1
3         | 1
4         | 4
5         | 4
7         | 7
8         | 7
11        | 11
12        | 11
```

### Construindo um clique

Como estamos assumindo que o grafo é um conjunto de cliques desconexos, detectar cada um desses cliques é só fazer uma junção da tabela `ALUNOS_IRMAOS` com ela mesma (mais sobre auto junção [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214566/64969) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214626/64969)).

```
SELECT
    AI1.COD_ALUNO,
    CASE
        WHEN AI1.COD_ALUNO < min(AI2.COD_ALUNO_IRMAO)
        THEN AI1.COD_ALUNO
        ELSE min(AI2.COD_ALUNO_IRMAO)
    END AS COD_IRMANDADE
FROM
    ALUNOS_IRMAOS AI1
        LEFT JOIN ALUNOS_IRMAOS AI2
            ON AI1.COD_ALUNO = AI2.COD_ALUNO
GROUP BY AI1.COD_ALUNO
```

Note que o `case` e o `min` garantem que o `COD_IRMANDADE` seja sempre o menor possível para o clique.

### Consulta inteira

Posso pegar a consulta do clique de irmandade e usá-la na consulta final como uma CTE ou como uma subconsulta. Eu acho mais elegente como CTE:

```
WITH IRMANDADE AS (
  SELECT
      AI1.COD_ALUNO,
      CASE
          WHEN AI1.COD_ALUNO < min(AI2.COD_ALUNO_IRMAO)
          THEN AI1.COD_ALUNO
          ELSE min(AI2.COD_ALUNO_IRMAO)
      END AS COD_IRMANDADE
  FROM
      ALUNOS_IRMAOS AI1
          LEFT JOIN ALUNOS_IRMAOS AI2
              ON AI1.COD_ALUNO = AI2.COD_ALUNO
  GROUP BY AI1.COD_ALUNO
)
SELECT
    A.COD_ALUNO, A.NM_ALUNO, A.NM_PAI, A.NM_MAE, I.COD_IRMANDADE
FROM ALUNOS A 
    LEFT JOIN IRMANDADE I
        ON A.COD_ALUNO = I.COD_ALUNO
```

Resultado:

```
COD_ALUNO | NM_ALUNO | NM_PAI  | NM_MAE   | COD_IRMANDADE
1         | GABRIEL  | SERGIO  | CELIA    | 1
2         | VITOR    | SERGIO  | CELIA    | 1
3         | GEOVANNE | SERGIO  | CELIA    | 1
4         | BRUNO    | WAGNER  | PAULA    | 4
5         | PEDRO    | WAGNER  | PAULA    | 4
6         | LARISSA  | TIAGO   | LAURA    | (null)
7         | GRAÇA    | PEDRO   | ISADORA  | 7
8         | MELISSA  | PEDRO   | ISADORA  | 7
9         | ENZO     | RAFAEL  | CAROLINE | (null)
10        | RAFAEL   | RAFAEL  | CELIA    | (null)
11        | MARIANE  | DANIEL  | MAITE    | 11
12        | TATIANE  | DANIEL  | MAITE    | 11
13        | MARIA    | RODOLFO | DANIELA  | (null)
```

Perceba que até mesmo os `null`s que você tinha previsto na resposta desejada ocorrem aqui. Para pegar índices consecutivos de irmandade, precisaria usar um `ROW_NUMBER` sobre a CTE `IRMANDADE`.

Veja [executando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c896/55)

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu estava procurando, ótima resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o jeito mais fácil seja agrupar pela combinação de nome dos pais (desprezando as combinações que são os dois vazios). Isso considera que os nomes sejam únicos:

```
WITH PARENTALIDADE AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.NM_PAI, A.NM_MAE) AS COD_UNICO_DOS_IRMAOS,
         ISNULL(A.NM_PAI, '') AS NM_PAI,
         ISNULL(A.NM_MAE, '') AS NM_MAE,
         COUNT(1) AS OCORRENCIAS
    FROM ALUNOS A
   WHERE A.NM_PAI IS NOT NULL
      OR A.NM_MAE IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY NM_PAI,
            NM_MAE
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT A.*,
       P.COD_UNICO_DOS_IRMAOS
  FROM ALUNOS A
       LEFT JOIN PARENTALIDADE P ON P.NM_PAI = ISNULL(A.NM_PAI, '')
                                AND P.NM_MAE = ISNULL(A.NM_MAE, '')
```

A estrutura da tabela me parece falha, mas com a atual e considerando que essas falhas podem ocasionar inconsistência essa solução parece ser viável.

Você pode conferir [**aqui o fiddle do exemplo em funcionamento**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55565e/1)

Comment: Ele tem uma tabela `ALUNOS_IRMAOS` que agrupa os irmãos, então creio que não seja necessário (nem bom) fazer a junção pelos nomes dos pais.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a tabela de irmãos dele não tá legal, porque uma pessoa pode ser irmão da outra e de uma terceira sem que a segunda e a terceira sejam irmãos, complica demais a lógica e parece ter furos

Comment: Isso é verdade, mas ainda assim plausível. Imagine dois casais com um filho (filhos 1 e 2), eles se separam e se casam com os cônjuges trocados, tendo os filhos 3 e 4. Então, 1 é irmão do 3 e do 4, 2 é irmão do 3 e do 4, porém 1 não é irmão de 2 nem 3 é irmão de 4

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu entendo isso, porém você não consegue bater as informações sem considerar o nome dos pais. Aliás, até consegue, mas é extremamente complexo

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, neste caso você tem um relacionamento de muitos para muitos, sempre que isso é representado no modelo lógico é necessário uma outra tabela para representar de forma normalizada no modelo relacional. Por exemplo: Neste caso poderia criar uma nova tabela chamada "Familia" ou "Irmandade", nela haveria um ID para cada irmandade e a relação de cada aluno (chaves estrangeiras).

```
CD_IRMANDADE CD_ALUNO
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            4
2            5
```

Segue um link com exemplo de como tratar relacionamentos de muitos para muitos.
[Tipos de relacionamento](http://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplo-pratico-regras-e-tipos-de-relacionamentos-sql-server-2008-parte-3/18409)

Comment: Como seria para o caso de pais divorciados que tem filhos no outro casamento?

Comment: A relação proposta não é de pais para filhos e sim de irmãos. Uma pessoa poderia estar em mais de uma irmandade ou família. Por exemplo, o aluno 3 poderia estar na irmandade 1, junto com os alunos 2 e 3 e na irmandade 10, junto com o aluno 15

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).