# View com SELECT duplo da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-select, sql-view

Preciso montar uma VIEW com três campos, porém um depende do outro pra ser calculado (dois deles são da mesma tabela em linhas diferentes preciso "linka-los"), como faço pra agregar esses campo em um lugar só?
Os select's são os seguintes:

```
SELECT Referencia FROM ZSF053 WHERE TpFat = 'ZREK'

SELECT Doc_orig FROM ZFI003 WHERE Referencia = (utiliza as referencias do select acima)

SELECT Referencia FROM ZFI003 WHERE Num_doc = (utiliza os Doc_orig do select acima)
```

Comment: Você já conhece como fazer `inner join` de duas tabelas? Estou perguntando isso para saber o como explicar pra você, não estou querendo parecer um "sabichão" nem te julgando para baixo, só quero conhecer o terreno

Comment: Os dois ultimos select são da mesma tabela?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero vide resposta do rLinhares

Comment: Sim eu conheço como fazer inner join de duas tabelas,

Comment: O meu problema é que os dois últimos selects são da mesma tabela, em condições diferentes, e pra achar um preciso do select do outro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu ia responder parecido colocando alias nas tabelas, só queria confirmar se eram da mesma tabela(me pareceu que dava para fazer com um único join)

Comment: @W.S.Silva fazer autojunção, ou junção/ _join_ de uma tabela com ela mesma, funciona exatamente da mesma forma que uma junção tradicional, mas força você a usar _alias_ para as tabelas. Vide resposta do rLinhares, ele fez uma autojunção de `ZFI003` consigo mesma

Comment: @CaiqueRomero somos 3 então xD

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214563/64969

Comment: Eu não sabia que dava pra fazer um Join de uma tabela com ela mesma, é o que eu precisa, muito obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da pergutna, podes testar a consulta como abaixo:

```
SELECT ZS.Referencia, ZF1.Doc_orig, ZF2.Referencia
FROM ZSF053 ZS
JOIN ZFI003 ZF1 ON ZS.Referencia = ZF1.Referencia
JOIN ZFI003 ZF2 ON ZF1.Doc_orig = ZF2.Doc_orig
WHERE ZS.TpFat = 'ZREK'
```

Como comentado na pergunta por [Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado), é bom você dar uma estudada nos comandos de **[*join*](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930)**.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é porque você é a referência :p já corrigi, vlw

Comment: Obrigado pelo elogio =] Eu recomendaria como leitura aprofundada algumas respostas já existentes aqui no SOpt. Eu achei [essa resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214566/64969) no assunto, abordando a montagem da consulta através da álgebra relacional. Vou linkar a pergunta como relacionada, então sinta-de a vontade para citar ou não na sua resposta

Answer (score 2):

A solução do @rLInhares resolve bem esse cenário, apenas para citar, como uma segunda alternativa caso o `JOIN` não seja possível, pode também aninhar os `SELECT`. Pegando o seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT Referencia 
  FROM ZFI003 
 WHERE Num_doc IN (SELECT Doc_orig 
                     FROM ZFI003 
                    WHERE Referencia IN (SELECT Referencia 
                                           FROM ZSF053 
                                          WHERE TpFat = 'ZREK'))
```

Nesse caso acima, usei `IN` no lugar de `=` para o caso da *query* retornar mais de um registro, mas também poderia limitar usando `TOP` por exemplo:

```
SELECT Referencia 
  FROM ZFI003 
 WHERE Num_doc = (SELECT TOP 1 Doc_orig 
                     FROM ZFI003 
                    WHERE Referencia IN (SELECT TOP 1 Referencia 
                                           FROM ZSF053 
                                          WHERE TpFat = 'ZREK'))
```

Apenas como nota caso alguém precise de uma outra forma de resolver